# Targeting the sibling of a parent element in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to target the sibling of a parent element, but it's not firing.
From prior experience and in looking at other examples I should just be able to add in 'parentElement' to have it move up a level in the dom tree like in this w3 example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp

Working example of my issue here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4M9OTXD3D42

I've asked basically the same question before - which was successfully answered (different code/issue). But, it's still proving a sticking point.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-sibling-child");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion-sibling-child {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;  
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="accordion-sibling-child">Accordion thats a child of a sibling to the expansion panel</a>
<div/>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor... </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it you attempting exactly? Are you wanting one accordion drawer activation to close the other drawer? Is there a reason you've chosen to place the toggle `<a>` in different structures? Is there a reason you've chosen not to use event delegation? It appears you've overcomplicated a fairly easy concept.

Comment: Looks like I've confused things a bit. If you follow this link  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4M9OTXD3D42 you'll see the issue. The first accordion works, but the second doesn't.

Comment: Why different structures for your accordion?

Comment: In terms of event delegations - that's just the way W3 reccommend to creating an accordion. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp If there's a simpler I'm all ears :)

Comment: I only want the not working version. The 'working' version is there purely as a comparison/to show where I'm at.

Comment: Updated question to improve clarity.

Comment: You cannot compare something that is completely different. Again, you've completely overcomplicated something that is utterly simple to do. I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: Not sure how I misstepped but thanks for taking the time.

Comment: The problem is that your HTML structure is not what you think it is. `<div/>` should be `</div>`; then it'll work.

Comment: Thank you very much melpomene. I thought I was going mad! I should've just pasted it all into my regular editor.

Comment: wow - good catch @melpomene - Brucie - you asked for a better version using event delegation. Checkout this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/riqiqiqepa/1/edit?html,css,js,output) - It is basically three lines of code with auto-closing accordions. If you don't want that, comment out the first line in the event handler. Hope you can see what I meant earlier.

Comment: Thanks very much Randy :)  And yeah, that's a whole heck of a lot simpler!